# .net webapi manipulate response (prepend object with ")]}',\n")

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for a way to prepend Web API 2 response with following string 
`)]}',\n`.

You probably know why. It's JSON Hijacking protection. I have a solution for .Net MVC regular controllers, but no for Web API.

In MCVC i have special `JsonNetResponse` Object where i can do following:

```
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.None);
response.Write(")]}',\n");
response.Write(serializedObject);
```

I Have no idea where I could manipulate response after action execution. 
Maybe i don't know much about Web API request life cycle. I will try to search more for sure.

I want to do it for all kind of requests: POST, GET, PUT, etc .

Any suggestions?

Comment: check DelegatingHandler, override SendAsync and return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [`DelegatingHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.118).aspx). You can derive it in order to hook into the Web API pipeline and override its `SendAsync` method:

```
public class JsonProtector : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        // Manipulate response here.
        return response;
    }
}
```

For general knowledge, this is what the Web API pipeline consists of:

[image: Web API pipeline]

More on that [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)

Comment: Thank you very much. I still cant figure out how to modify response  in fact. 
In fact I could read 
string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
But how to "put it" back into Content?

Answer (score 0):

ok so as @Yuval Itzchakov sugested solution was to extend DelegatingHandler.
Here is full code:

```
public class JsonProtector : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        // Manipulate response here.
        if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            responseData = ")]}',\n" + responseData;
            var repo = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseData));
            response.Content = new StreamContent(repo);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```